# iPad and iPhone browser rotating images on site?

Tags: css, images, iphone, ipad

I am experiencing an odd occurance on a site I'm building right now where images are displayed 90 degrees different from how they are supposed to, but while maintaining the normal dimensions of the image that I specified. This only occurs on the Safari in iPad and iPhone for me... all other browsers do not have this problem.

[image]

Any ideas?

The page in question can be seen here: http://www.andrewpeterson.com/i-had-to-be-a-perfect-gentleman-with-the-princesses/

Comment: Uuuh .. I do not have any Apple device or browser to check .. but maybe they reading EXIF info (especially rotation)? Try removing all extra info from these images (at least one, use image compressors, like this one: http://www.punypng.com/) and replace your image with "optimized" version, then see if it helps (make sure the browser has current image version, so clear caches).

Comment: +1 for problem I have never *ever* seen before. A couple further data points: IrfanView and Photoshop both also load the top image rotated as in Mobile WebKit/Safari. Desktop Safari does not. This does support the idea it's in the image metadata, though there's a lot in there and I haven't found which specific property is doing it here using Photoshop's browser(I don't deal with EXIF much, though). Should give you a starting place, though. @LazyOne, if you want to repost as an actual answer, I'll vote it up. I just ran the first image through PunyPNG, and that worked for me.

Comment: I did it :) Thnx Su'

Comment: Had the same problem, removing the meta data worked!

Comment: solved the problem :) If you think its cumbersome to get programs to delete the metadata you can open the image in paint (included in windows), mark it and copy, choose new image, paste your copy and save.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uuuh .. I do not have any Apple device or browser to check .. but it looks like they reading **EXIF** metadata (in particular rotation).

I have opened one of this images in XnView -- image is displayed 90 degrees rotated.

Try removing all extra info from these images (do it for at least one image). Use image compressors, like this one: [punypng.com](http://www.punypng.com/) (or any other tool that can remove metadata details .. or just rotate it and save again) and replace your image with "optimized" version.

When checking again on iPad, make sure the browser has current image version, so clear caches.

P.S.
Thnx Su'

Comment: That was it! What a strange thing to effect a web browser. I ended up using IrfanView to fix it (opening the file and resaving it without metadata) and now everything displays fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using JPEG and PNG Stripper http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=30
then remove all information related to the metadata of Image.
It works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to manually override the EXIF rotation metadata, if the image is saved in the correct orientation in MS Windows.  In Windows Explorer, right-click on the image file and select "Rotate clockwise".  Do this 4 times to rotate the image all the way around, and then the image will have the correct orientation for all systems.  Then you can upload the image to your web server.

Comment: This did not work for me. Perhaps Windows Explorer retains the metadata in WIndows 10 but didn't maintain it in previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

I have filed this as a bug with Apple via [Apple's Bug Reporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com). If this is important to you and you have sample data, it can't hurt to have more than one report on the issue. The screenshot below should highlight the problem, and in the off chance an Apple employee glances at this post, the problem ID is 11299426.

[image: Inconsistent Rotation Behavior]